# Invalid package identity name - mystery prefix being added preventing upload to Microsoft store

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I'm having issues re-publishing and submitting an app to the Windows store, specifically in uploading the application package.  The first submission was successful in terms of package upload but had other issues, so now I'm re-publishing.

In my manifest I have the packing name of "AdrianK.LorpWormhole", but when uploading the package I get this error:

> Lorp.Wormhole_1.1.5.0_x86_x64_arm_bundle.appxupload29.6 MB
>
> - Invalid package identity name: AdrianK.LorpWormhole (expected: 24206AdrianK.34586DA8BF322)
> - Invalid package family name: AdrianK.LorpWormhole_n5r4weagqr54a (expected: 24206AdrianK.34586DA8BF322_n5r4weagqr54a)

I have no idea where the 24206 prefix has come from.  I did a search in my code and found some matches in an xml file that looks like it's part of the store association.

To fix this I:

1. Completely deleted the app from the Dev portal (https://developer.microsoft.com)
2. Deleted all "24206" from the code base (which was only in the aforementioned xml file.
3. Re-created the app packages.
4. Reserved the App name "Lorp Wormhole" through the dev portal
5. Created a new submission, went straight to Packages and uploaded the new package.

I still get the error.  Looking at the App Identity page on the portal it reports the package name with the 24206 prefix.  But I have no idea where this is coming from.

The thing that mystifies me is that I'm only giving the dev portal two pieces of information: the name I reserve and the package; so either the package has some issue i'm not seeing or the store is doing something I'm not expecting - maybe a hang-up from the previous submission?

The 24206 prefix also pollutes the Package Family Name (PFN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix is related to developer's account. All app packages published by one certain developer have the same prefix.The package identity name is different from your app's display name and it will not effect your app's name shown to users.

If you associate your app with store in Visual Studio, your package's identity name and family name will get the right format automatically.